# SelectMethod in objectDatasource getting called multiple times with multiple datapagerfield

Tags: asp.net, listview, objectdatasource, datapager

Ok, so here is the setup.  I am building a page that has a listview, a datapager, and 3 datapagerfield (2 x NextPreviousPagerField, 1 x NumericPagerField), and a objectdatasource to tide all of this together.

It was all working fine until I put a breakpoint into the SelectMethod specified in the objectdatsource control.  It seems like that for each datapagerfield control, it is calling the selectmethod and selectcount method.  Hence, whenever a user paged, it calls the database 6 times instead of 2 (I don't have caching turned on atm).  If I remove one datapagerfield, it will remove 2 calls.

Now this is build in asp.net 3.5 SP1 in VS2008.  When I copied the same code files to a asp.net 4.0 VS2010 solution, it duplicate call seems to be gone.

Is this a bug in asp.net 3.5 SP1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you should be using the OnSelecting event.

What happens is that ObjectDataSource calls the method SelectMethod **twice**

1. First time it gets the data.
2. Next time it gets the count.

So I think you have to implement the OnSelecting event

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList" SelectCountMethod="GetListCount" 
    OnSelecting="ods_Selecting">
    TypeName="Website.Test" EnablePaging="true" />
```

and then cancel the event when the ObjectDataSource tries to call the count method.

```
 protected void ods_Selecting(object sender,
                ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.ExecutingSelectCount)
      {
           //Cancel the event   
           return;
      }
}
```

You can use the link below so that another db call is not made to fetch the count.
http://www.unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2005/12/28/818.aspx

Hope this helps.