# ObjectDataSource SelectCountMethod not Executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

This is about myIdea-project-during-worktime project.  I am using an ObjectDataSource to populate a GridView.  For some reason the "page" part (that is supposed to come at the bottom of the of the grid) is not coming up.  I have looked at the answers for other similar question here but haven't been able to figure out what is going wrong with my code.

The GridView looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
            runat="server" 
            AllowPaging="True"
            PageSize="10" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="rowid"
            DataSourceID="PopulateGridView">
 ........
 </asp:GridView>
```

The GridView is using ObjectDataSource "PopulateGridView".  "PopulateGridView" looks like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource 
ID="PopulateGridView" 
runat="server"
TypeName="SurveyItemInfo"
SelectMethod="GetPagedData"
EnablePaging="True"
SelectCountMethod="GetRowCount"
StartRowIndexParameterName="startRow"
MaximumRowsParameterName="pageSize"
SortParameterName="sortColumns"
OnObjectCreated="SurveyItemInfo_ObjectCreated">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

A class "SurveyItemInfo" is created with methods like "GetPagedData" and "GetRowCount".
GetPagedData looks like this:

```cs
 public DataTable GetPagedData(string sortColumns, int startRow, int pageSize)
    {
        // datatable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sql;

        // Create connection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

        // Create command
        sql = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.epm_ListSurveyItemForReportPaged";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportid", reportid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startRow", startRow);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageSize", pageSize);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageSize", 50);

        // Execute command
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            //reader.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

I am using a sproc from this method to get the paged data to grid.  Note that I have commented out the line where the sproc is getting its 3rd parameter for page size (number of rows).  I am using a hard-coded value here to test purpose.

When debugging through I have found that the values for parameter startRow and pageSize for method GetPagedData are zero.  Also I am not sure about it but isn't the method for ObjectdataSource's SelectCountMethod (GetRowCount) supposed to get executed once?  It is not.

This method has the following code:

```
public int GetRowCount()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.data_SurveyItem where reportid=" + reportid.ToString(), conn))
        {
            return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

So the issue is numeric page links to browse to different pages is not coming up at the bottom of the GridView.  For both GridView and ObjectDataSource paging and sorting are enabled (although I am not using sorting).  I am not exactly sure what else I am missing.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why your objectdatasource select parameters isn't configured?  <SelectParameters>

Comment: Sorry, could not get back to you any earlier.  I will check and will get back to you.

Comment: I am actually using the example code from this [link](http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=23).  Here no select parameters are being set.

Comment: @ahmjt: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885073/selectmethod-in-objectdatasource-getting-called-multiple-times-with-multiple-dat/4343632#4343632

Comment: Thanks @dhinesh for the link.  For some reason, not sure why, once I removed grid's stylesheet all things started coming up!